# Create XML file on local machine using BCP

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, bcp

I create C# application for generate XML file. I use `bcp.exe`:

```
command.CommandText = "EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp.exe \"select * from Primer.dbo.TempLot 
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT, Elements\"  queryout C:\\new\\outxml1.XML -w -r -T'";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But when I start this application on local machine XML file created on server (where MS SQL Server). How save xml file on local hard drive?

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1071870-338-1.aspx

Comment: @har07 i see this, it not working

Comment: The server doesn't know anything about drive letters other than what it can see. You can either use a UNC path ('\\machinename\sharedfolder') or map a drive on the server to point to your local machine.